# Why should the dimensionless coefficients in aerodynamics be less than one?

Tags: aerodynamics

Why should the dimensionless coefficients in aerodynamics be less than one?
Like the lift coefficient , drag coefficien, ect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That depends on the reference used to normalize them. Normally, this is the dynamic pressure and the reference area. If the force to be expressed as a coefficient is smaller than the product of dynamic pressure and area, of course the coefficient will be smaller than one.

If the force is negative, the coefficient will be negative, too. What is positive and negative is a matter of definition, and there is no reason why coefficients should not be negative, too.

Comment: Thank you. But why does dividing the force by the dynamic pressure and reference area normalize it ?

Comment: Pressure times area is force. Divide a force by a force and you get a dimensionless number, a coefficient.

Comment: Why do we specifically choose to divide by the dynamic pressure ? And could we divide by other forms of pressure and if yes what would be the difference of meaning between the obtained coefficients?

Comment: @ZahraaKhalife: Dynamic pressure is what causes aerodynamic forces. If we use ambient pressure, for example, the coefficients would vary with the square of speed, making them unusable for comparisons between different speeds. The pressure acts on the wing surface, so if we use a different area, say the size of the pilot's cushion, we would also lose the ability to compare between differently sized aircraft.